# How can I get the distinct values of queryset?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have this query such as

```
query1 = A.objects.filter(a=a).values('color__red')
```

And the debugger told me that :

```
<QuerySet [{'color__red': 'yes'}, {'color__red': 'yes'}, {'color__red': 'yes'}, {'color__red': 'yes'}, {'color__red': 'yes'}, {'color__red': 'yes'}, {'color__red': 'yes'}, {'color__red': 'yes'}, {'color__red': 'yes'}, {'color__red': 'yes'}]>
```

I would like to count the number of distinct values of color__red (in my case it is one because `color__red = 'yes'` but sometimes it can be 2)

I know in the case of an arrays I have to do a `len(list(set(array)))` but I don't achieve to get the value in the case of queryset.

Could you help me please ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

You can add [**`.distinct()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) to the queryset:

```
query1 = A.objects.filter(a=a).values('color__red').distinct()
```

In case you want to *count* the number of distinct objects, you can use [**`.count()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.count):

```
n_colors = A.objects.filter(a = a).values('color__red').distinct().count()
```

You can also define an [**`.aggregate(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate) here, and work with a [**`Count`** expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#id8) here:

```
n_colors = A.objects.filter(a=a).aggregate(n_colors = Count('color__red', distinct=True))['n_colors']
```

The uniqueness filter will then be performed on the database level. So Django will construct a query like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT app_color.red
FROM app_a
LEFT OUTER JOIN app_color ON app_color.a_id = a.app_a.id
WHERE app_a.a = a
```

and for the `.count()` query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT app_color.red
     FROM app_a
     LEFT OUTER JOIN app_color ON app_color.a_id = a.app_a.id
     WHERE app_a.a = a)
```

with the aggregate we get:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT app_color.red) AS n_colors
FROM app_a
LEFT OUTER JOIN app_color ON app_color.a_id = a.app_a.id
WHERE app_a.a = a
```

So this is done at the database, which is usually faster, and furthermore the amount of data that is transferred from the database to the application is significantly less.